# Rudin theorem 5.19, MVT for vector function

Tags: real-analysis

$f$ is a continuous function from $[a,b]$ to $R^k$ and $f$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ then

$\left|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right|\leq |f'(c)|\,\,\text{for some $c\in(a,b)$}.$

I simply let $f(x) = (f_1(x), ..., f_k(x))$ and expanded and found that we can change the inequality to an equality, why is an equality no good? (unless I did some calculation mistake somewhere)

Comment: $f$ needs to be differentiable. You can't necessarily find a $c$ that works for all elements of the vector ${f(b)-f(a) \over b-a}$. It is not hard to construct an example that illustrates.

Comment: I don't understand, the statement says $f$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply the mean value theorem to each component, then the $c$ given by the theorem may not be the same for each component.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

Example:

$f(t) =(\cos t, \sin t )$ , $t \in [0, π/2]$.

$$|f(π/2) -f(0)|=√2 <$$

$$ |π/2-0||-\sin r,\cos r|=π/2,$$
$$0<r <π/2$$.